# Join two jsonb on keys and output values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

The example setup:

```
CREATE TABLE configs (
  device_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  elements jsonb   not null
-- more columns omitted
);

INSERT INTO configs (device_id, elements) VALUES
   (1, '{"00": "FLOOR", "01": "CEILING", "02" : "MIDDLE"}');
   
CREATE TABLE logs (
  record_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id int,
  record jsonb
-- more columns omitted
);

INSERT INTO logs(record_id, device_id, record) VALUES
   (1, 1, '{"00": 5, "01": 10, "02": 15}'),
   (2, 1, '{"00": 6, "01": 4, "02": 9}');
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=56dca69247ed407ee110a8d66426c536)

What I am trying to do is setup a join on the device_id and the key in each json.  I came up with this:

```
select record_id, e.device_id, e.key, e.value as "element", d.value  
from
(
    select device_id, a.key, a.value
    FROM configs, jsonb_each_text(elements) a
)e
inner join 
(
    select record_Id, device_id, a.key, a.value 
    from logs, jsonb_each(record) a
)d on (e.key = d.key AND e.device_id = d.device_id)
```

which works but I guess I just want to know if

1. There is some more simplified way to write this that I'm overlooking.
2. What sort of index could I apply on these tables to speed such a query up?
3. If I wanted to just output a json string of the element with the value i.e.

   {"FLOOR": 5, "CEILING": 10, "MIDDLE": 15}

   how could I accomplish that (with easiest query possible)?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Don't do that. Use a relational data model instead of storing a table in a JSON. Then your problem will vanish.

Comment: The problem is that the elements are different for every device AND some devices have more elements than others. Also the elements can change randomly on different days. So I WAS using the relational model but it presented a lot of problems due to the constant changes.

Comment: Or at the very least helping with the query for question 3 could get me back to a relational table design which is why I asked